# Initializing UIImageView not working

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, init

I am new to Objective C and i am trying to make a game, thing is when my missile hits a ship i want it gone, but when i fire again i want it initialized whet i want to fire again

image is firsty initialize in ViewControler.h

```
IBoutlet UIImageView *Missile;
```

then when i try to use in a fire method with this code

```
Missile = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(54, 145, 65, 30)];
Missile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"missile_fire.png"];
Missile.hidden = NO;
```

it crashes, i guess that is because it is already initialized, but then I do this

```
self->Missile = nil;
```

then there is no crash but also no image after initialization i put above, what i need is it to initialize when i am ready to fire with position and image, and to be gone when it hits

Comment: You have syntax errors, you've made something an IBOutlet that I think you don't really want to be, you haven't added the missile to the view so it'll display, you don't need ".png", you don't need self->, simply setting Missile to nil won't make it disappear without removing it from the view. Nothing that should crash though. Need more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize as:

```
UIImageView* missile;
```

Then,

```
missile = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
missile.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"name"];
[self.view addSubview:missile];
```

When it crashes:

```
[missile removeFromSuperview];
```

You're gonna need more code if you want that missile to move though.

Also, you should have it be `missile` instead of `Missile` because it is not a class. Classes get uppercase first letter but variables do not (`missile` is a `UIImageView` object)

Comment: ok, i get that now, but the next thing bothering me is that when i remove it form superview it does not free my memory
-(void)Move{
    missile.center = CGPointMake(missile.center.x + 2, missile.center.y);
    if (missile.center.x > 400){
    
        [missile removeFromSuperview];
        missile = nil;
        [Moving invalidate];
        
    }
    
}
i initialized like you said but when i do the clenup thing it doesnt free my memory

Answer (score 2):

if you want to work with image without storyboard dont use `IBoutlet` beacuse `IBoutlet` is used when you want to work with storyboard for connect object to class.

Use only:

```
UIImageView *Missile;
```